# Java: Dealing with Exponentiation

Tags: java, exponentiation

I have a problem with this program where I have to calculate the value of base^expo, and the base is a real number whereas the exponent is an integer. With `(95.123)^12` I'm expecting `548815620517731830194541.899025343415715973535967221869852721`, but my program produces `548815620517732160000000.000000`, which is wrong. Please suggest a better approach.

```
// declare variables and read values
double myBase = scan.nextDouble(); 
int myExponent = scan.nextInt();

// display result
System.out.printf("%f", Math.pow(myBase, myExponent));
```

Comment: The bigger doubles get, the less accurate they are.

Comment: Always use `BigDecimal`'s for higher precision or accuracy!

Comment: I recommend you having a look at "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: As others say, use `BigDecimal`. If you have many such operations to perform and you seek better performance, you may want to have a look at apfloat as well.

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating-point roundoff.

Answer (score 5):

try to use `BigDecimal`

example:

```
BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal("some number");
int exponent = ..;

BigDecimal result = base.pow(exponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `double` type in Java is a `IEEE` double and has only 53 bits of precision.  Because of this, you will get the closest `double` value possible to the true answer.

Because of the large magnitude of the result, the closest `double` values are quite a bit more than `1` apart.  You can verify this by calling the [`Math.ulp` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-double-) (unit in the last place).

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(Math.pow(myBase, myExponent)));
```

This outputs:

```
6.7108864E7
```

Even with the precision, consecutive `double` values are 67 million apart.

As an alternative, you can use `BigDecimal`s instead, e.g.

```
BigDecimal myBase= new BigDecimal(scan.next());
int myExponent= scan.nextInt();

//displays result
System.out.println(myBase.pow(myExponent));
```

Output:

```
548815620517731830194541.899025343415715973535967221869852721
```

Note that [`pow` here takes an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow-int-), not another `BigDecimal`.